# Applying .htaccess rules (mod_deflate, mod_expires, mod_headers, mod_mime, mod_rewrite)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm hoping someone can help point us in the right direction, our website is currently very slow due to no GZIP or compression, after using an extension we are present when trying to enable the extension with this error.

I'm running opencart 2.x

> Applying .htaccess rules for compression/browser cache is not
>   compatible with your server setup. Please make sure you have the
>   following Apache modules enabled: mod_deflate, mod_expires,
>   mod_headers, mod_mime, mod_rewrite.

I've searched high and low for answers and have not come across a fix for this error. I've also added lines of text to your .htaccess with no success, so I'm unsure if I've added the correct text.

> I also know my host accepts these rules,

Steven

Comment: First of all STOP SPAMMING TAGS TO GET ATTENTION. This has nothing to do with javascript, html, or opencart. Secondly the answer is in the error: "Please make sure you have the following Apache modules enabled: mod_deflate, mod_expires, mod_headers, mod_mime, mod_rewrite". Enable those modules like it says to do. I'm sure you can search for how to do that on your favorite search engine.

Comment: When did this community get so hostile? They are enabled, that's exactly what im saying.

Comment: When people stopped playing by the rules

Comment: This still does not help the situation...

Comment: Ok argue with me then. You know more than me. See how much help you're getting? This is a programming help site not a "I don't know how to administrate my web server" help site. You wasted my time by spamming programming tags for a non programming question. If they're enabled then why would your server say they aren't?

Comment: Here's a nifty idea!! Why don't you at least show the .htaccess file contents so maybe someone could tell you what you are doing wrong?

Comment: Figured it out, enjoy arguing online :)

Comment: Grats on figuring it out. Very nice of you to show the solution so that others can benefit.